# mysql php insert

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a question, not sure if this is a good way of coding.
I have a table with 75 fields, and no, it can't be normalize, and even if I normalize it, i can only collapsed the data to an array using implode and even that i will still have 65 fields. i have codes that access this table, however, it doesn't need all the fields, so in my code, with an insert i am able to get by, by calling only the fields that i need, and it still runs just fine, my question is, can i continue working like this:

so e.g., instead of this:

```
insert into table(75 fields) values(values)
```

i can get by, by doing this:

```
insert into table (only fields i need here) values (values)
```

will php and mysql eventually break the above?

Comment: Oh lord where to begin.. A table with 75 fields? I am very confident this can be normalized to several smaller tables. Why have you got fields that you don't need or use? Will your code be deprecated? Not for a while no, but your database design is really not sounding great. Ontop of that, there really isn't any code here, so you're not going to get much of an answer.

Comment: Chris, I can't normalize it as its all monetary values and it belongs to one user, and the tables already are in normalize form for things that can be normalize. i thought the same thing, and there is no way around it. and yes 75 was huge, this is after i recoded the what the previous coder had created.

Comment: Why should it make a difference that the fields are monetary prevents it being normalized? Normalization has nothing to do wth the datatypes of the columns

Comment: no normalization has nothing to do with datatypes, but somethings like the data structure with this application can't be normalized. it's not possible. everything was tried, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

i think its the update which you looking for.

with `UPDATE` you can just update some fields you want.

with `INSERT` you cant . forexample if you have some columns which have nut null key. pr primary keys. and so on.

Comment: really, thanks for letting me know i guess i need to change this now.

Answer (score 0):

No it shouldnt break it but you have to be careful that none of those fields requires a value. if they do then you cant enter null.

Comment: great thanks. i guess it makes sense why the code is still working.

Answer (score -1):

No, php and MySQL won't break this.

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment as it contains no information about why or how it would break it.

Comment: nice, thanks for your input. 75 fields is huge, it was orignally over 75 and managed to get it to 75, so calling 75 fields each time wasn't going to be cool:-)

Comment: sorry how do i add a comment again?